# How to send cookie with http request in Scala without using any other library?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have a JSESSIONID that I need to set on my http request. I'm using play framework. Tried: `WS.url(XML_MNP_URL).withHeaders("Cookie" -> headerSessionId)` but it doesn't work. Please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add cookies to a request using `withHeaders` use `COOKIE`, not `"Cookie"` when setting the headers:

```
WS.url(XML_MNP_URL).withHeaders(COOKIE -> "foo=bar")
```

The request will now include `Cookie: foo=bar` as a header

Comment: hi, withCookies is used for set cookie for http response, I'm trying to set cookie for http request :(

Comment: @Duc Updated my answer to reflect sending a request with cookies instead of including them with a response.

Comment: thanks, actually figured that out myself today but it works with "Cookie", will try using COOKIE tomorrow. Thanks.